# Concern over using log4j2 AsynchronousLoggers in Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j2, java.util.concurrent, lmax

I would like to employ Log4j2 Asynchronous loggers within an Java EE 7 Applicatiosn.

This entails using the LMAX disruptor-3.0.0.jar or higher on the classpath.

I am concerned this breaks the rule related to starting "user" threads within a Java EE container.

Does the log4j2 automatic configuartion detect the presence of a Jee container? or do I need to pass log4j2 ManagedExecutorService? to use in WorkerPool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be right that using Async Loggers (or AsyncAppender, for that matter) breaks the J2EE rules. At the moment Log4j 2 creates its own ExecutorService (with a call to `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`).

I recommend that you create a feature request ticket on the [Log4j 2 Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2) to propose adding the ability for user code (or configuration) to specify a `ManagedExecutorService` for use by the Disruptor.